# CSS gradient square background from black to transparency

Tags: html, css

We have a div which has to be semi-transparent and semi-black, plus it has to go into 100% transparency to all the sides as a square gradient.

In other words: in the **centre** it is a `50%` black and `50%` opacity block (say: `400px width` and `200px height`) and around this block black colour is dying to 100% transparency to all the sides.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: @chiapa: we are looking for a help to implement it. What the sense to show wrong attempts? We are looking for ideas of how to implement it. I tried google but it did not really help. It does not refer to square gradients. Thanks

Comment: The sense to show wrong attempts is to show that you have actually tried something, and not just looking for an answer

Comment: don't worry anymore)) @matthewelsom answered without this))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 50% opacity div that fades to 0% opacity at the edges. 
Hope that helps.

```css
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.box .content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box::before {
    content: "";
    top: 50px; right: 50px; bottom: 50px; left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2em 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```